# Keyboard.GetState() is only working first time I start the application

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

We have just ported our application from XNA to MonoGame since we don't wanne be stuck with .NET 4.0
Almost everything worked fine, was some issue with fullscreen where I found a soloution too.

However, during the Update we check if there has been any input.
I use:

```
KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
```

First time it reacts and I get the result. This works until i do Game.Exit().
Then I start the game again by same command:

```
Game d = new Game();
d.Run();
```

After that is Keyboard.GetState() always empty. It won't recoginze any inputs from my keyboard. Mouse and touch is working the entire time.
What's wrong? Read a post about restating my PC but didn't help.

Comment: Seems as if input specific stuff is not disposed properly, causing key state events not get correctly setup during second initialization of `Game`. I'd suggest either filing an issue at their GitHub repo or dig around the source to pin down the cause.

Comment: I have moved my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102791/keyboard-getstate-only-work-first-time
However still without a sucessful result but with some comments and more information